# IO utilization for /dev/null redirection?

Tags: devices, io

I always use `nohup` to start my system. However, the output to `nohup` is so big that I'm thinking to redirect it to `/dev/null`. My concern is, will redirecting to `/dev/null` also incur some I/O operations like writing to a normal file?

Or, should I go down to the code level and remove all those logging info? (But I might need them).

My only concern is the I/O utilization & file size.

Answer (score 5):

Data written to `/dev/null` doesn't go anywhere. Since it isn't written to any file, there is no file size to have any impact on.

If a program writes to `/dev/null`, the system call takes place. But the system call returns almost immediately without writing the data anywhere. So there is I/O from the application's point of view, but not from the hardware's point of view.

Nobody but you can know whether the tiny cost of writing to `/dev/null` is too much. If you're concerned, benchmark.

Comment: Ya, what i'm afraid is the system call. Even tho it will be returned immediately, it still need to transfer from user space to kernel space to make the system calls - Wont invoking frequent system calls bad (even tho returned immediately)? Well, I was just curious, just in case someone already done some comparison...

Comment: @kuronue Frequent system calls aren't intrinsically bad. It's a compromise between development time and resource consumption. It's very dependent on how much output you have, only you have the data to decide.

Answer (score 2):

This feels a little like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What you should really be doing is adding the ability to control your logging level from either a configuration file or the command line using increasing numbers of `-v`'s, ala. `-vvv` as do many many command line tools.

Then you can still invoke your server using `nohup` and add/remove the `-vv..` switching, and only add it when necessary.

Additionally look at using a real logging facility like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), [log4perl](http://mschilli.github.io/log4perl/), log4X where X is whatever your language happens to be. Then you can control the loging level from a log4X .conf file and also specify things like log rotation etc.

Obviously you can redirect the logging as it stands to `/dev/null` but these are other options that you should also consider as a developer.

Comment: Yup, but im starting an app server that is built/used by many apps - which i dont have control on the logging level. Most of the apps simply throw everything to the stdout. However, from time to time, we need to refer to that .out during troubleshooting.

Comment: Oh I forgot: Changing at code level requires a lot of effort on their side. That's why I prefer to redirect to /dev/null if the impact is not big.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to /dev/null incurs a non-zero cost but if it affects your system performance, the author of the software has done something very wrong.  Calling sys_write() is highly optimized.  Writing the data you send to it does make its way through the various libraries and kernel systems until it hits the null driver. That path is highly efficient.

Yes, a program probably should have a flag that disables output, but if it doesn't and writing to /dev/null is a performance problem, you've got one weird system.

Remember that "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Editing the code to fix this is a waste of time unless you can first write a benchmark that shows that this is really the biggest performance bottleneck.

Historical note:

The original releases of Linux had a very slow /dev/null. It did a lot of processing just to throw out the data at the end.  There was an embarrassing benchmark (I can't find a link, sorry!) showing Linux's /dev/null was much slower than FreeBSD and Solaris (the popular Unix-like systems back then).  The next release of Linux had a much faster /dev/null.  Similarly the loopback NIC in Linux used to be very slow because it completely processed the packet, checking for CRC errors (which couldn't possibly be wrong), and doing other unnecessary work. A few embarrassingly bad benchmarks were published and soon things were fixed.